# Issue of open source E-cart NopCommerce template

Tags: templates, nopcommerce

Thanks in advance.
For any nopcommerce user, Do anyone use the template built by  OSshop.biz before???
i have tried the one named Luxury handbag store (linked below). When i run it, it turn out a error:

```
Theme 'FashionShoes' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Theme 'FashionShoes' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Theme 'FashionShoes' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.]
   System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(String themeName) +923
   System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(HttpContext context, String themeName) +73
   System.Web.UI.Page.InitializeThemes() +8700927
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +282
```

Is this the bug of this template or is my setting error?? I have followed every step in the manual already. Would anyone kindly help me ??? Thank You

[Template link](http://www.osshop.biz/Products/1-luxury-handbag-storenopcommerce150-ready.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. You have changed the default theme to FashionShoes and this was stored in your database. To get rid of this problem there are to options: First, just copy back the folder containing containing the FashionShoes theme in your theme folder and then run your website and change it back to whichever theme you like. Second (but I am not very sure...!) navigate to yourwebsite.com/administration and login and change the theme.

FYI: In case you do not know how to change the theme, just navigate to yourwebsite.com/administration and click on the setting and go to SEO table and change the theme from the dropdown list